# InvalidSelectorException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

В переменной могут попадаться символы которые используются и в Xpath, соответственно появляется синтаксическая ошибка, как это можно победить ?

Пример переменной (это просто пример, символы в ней могут быть разные):

```
string textElementa = "it ' is"
```

поиск элемента по Xpach:

```
IWebElement elem = diver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[normalize-space()='" + textElementa + "']"));
```

Сам Html код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>it</span> <span>'</span> <span>is</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ничего непонятено. покажите где и как вы это используете

Comment: @SeniorPomidor обновил - должно быть теперь понятно

Comment: contains() не хотите использовать?

Comment: и попробуйте заменить символы экранированием, скажем `textElementa.Replace("'","\'")`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor именно так и сделал вчера, но всё равно спасибо. https://imgur.com/9YGw4N3

Comment: если это решило вашу проблему, то оформите как ответ